# Ignore certain characters when comparing variables?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, variable

For example, If this is my script:

```
if [[ $yesno == "What's going on" ]]; then
```

Then how do I make it Ignore `'`, `?`, `,` and `.` for example?

So basically `Whats going on`, `What's going on`, `What's going on?` and `What's going on.` would all appear to be the same thing. I know that I can put `|| [[ $yesno == ".. ]]` to match multiple variables but I can't type out every single combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove all characters beside alphanumerical ones in your variable before the comparison:

```
$ yesno="What's going on?"
$ if [[ ${yesno//[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]/} == "Whats going on" ]]; then echo "OK";fi
OK
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want your specific examples to work you can use a bash regexp match

```
[[ $yesno =~ What\'?s\ going\ on[.?]? ]]
```

where we escape with backslash the quote and the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common and universal ways to do this would be to pipe the string into `grep` and check `grep`'s return code.  The `if` statement can check the exit code of any command or pipeline:

```
if echo "$yesno" | grep -q "What'*s *going *on[?.]*"; then
```

In addition to the characters you mentioned, this also allows 0 or more spaces in between words.

This construct should work on OS X, FreeBSD, GNU/Linux, and any other system which provides POSIX grep:

Comment: Careful with the quote marks -- I think they are ended prematurely. Also, the question is a little vague, but the intention may be to only match 0 or 1 punctuation marks; your current regexp (as you know) would allow multiple sequential quote marks.

Comment: Yea thanks total brain lapse. I can't believe I did that! :-).  Also the unquoted yesno variable.